# Composition: how to make a day and night world map?

Tags: graphics, geography, astronomy

Given the following world images:

```
night = Import["http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/55000/55167/earth_lights_lrg.jpg"]
day = Import["http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/57000/57752/land_shallow_topo_2048.tif"]
```

[image: day and night maps]

how would you use *Mathematica* to create an accurate “day and night map” (examples [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/sunearth.html) and [there](http://www.daylightmap.com/index.php)) of the Earth for a given date and time?

Comment: This question also has an answer (using *MMA* illustrations) on the [GIS site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17184/method-to-shade-or-overlay-a-raster-map-to-reflect-time-of-day-and-ambient-light/17190#17190).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let me first name your maps correctly (you switched night and day maps):

```
night= Import["http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/55000/55167/earth_lights_lrg.jpg"];
day= Import["http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/57000/57752/land_shallow_topo_2048.tif"];
```

The images have different sizes:

```
ImageDimensions[day]

(*
==> {2048, 1024}
*)

ImageDimensions[night]

(*
==> {2400, 1200}
*)
```

so, I rescale the night image. Artefacts (if any) will probably be less visible there.

```
night = ImageResize[night, ImageDimensions[day]];
```

Now, for the calculation of the mask we don't need to use external sources. `AstronomicalData` will do:

```
mask =
 Rasterize[
  RegionPlot[
   AstronomicalData["Sun", {"Altitude", {2012, 6, 21}, {lat, long}}] <
     0, {long, -180, 180}, {lat, -90, 90}, Frame -> None, 
   PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   AspectRatio -> (#2/#1 & @@ ImageDimensions[day])],
  ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[day]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then, stealing the `ImageCompose` idea from Yu-Sung:

```
pl=ImageCompose[night, SetAlphaChannel[day, mask]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Borrowing and adapting some code from the `Texture` doc page:

```
Show[
 Graphics3D[{White, Tube[{{0, 0, -1.4}, {0, 0, 1.4}}, .04]}],
 SphericalPlot3D[1 , {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, 1 - #4} &), 
  PlotStyle -> Texture[Show[pl, ImageSize -> 1000]], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, RotationAction -> "Clip"], 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, 
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For day/night Earth textures with matching dimensions, [this](http://www.shadedrelief.com/natural3/pages/textures.html) is one place to get them; you then no longer need to resize.

Comment: Actually the last plot does not work for me: I get !http://i.stack.imgur.com/peG10.png

Comment: @chris Do all the examples on the Texture doc page work for you?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries in fact they do.

Comment: @chris the final plot is not much different from what's in there. Could you try without Show and the Tube? For now, I suppose this is an issue of your graphics card.

Comment: I tried `SphericalPlot3D[1, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, 1 - #4} &), 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[Show[pl, ImageSize -> 1000]], 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, RotationAction -> "Clip"]` it's all white! :-)

Comment: @chris The last part is almost identical to the "Earth" example in the docs. Could you try pasting the above texture in th example itself to see if that works? If it doesn't I'm out of options.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries this works: `SphericalPlot3D[1 , {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, 1 - #4} &), 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 10], Texture[pl]], 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, RotationAction -> "Clip"]`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries its very odd; From a new session your code produces a while globe; if I then evaluate the doc earth example and your code again it works...

Comment: @chris I appear to have the same. Resizing the window seems to help quite often. I also notice that v8 and v9 react differently here.

Comment: sweet you could put a toothpick texture on that white thing sticking through the earth.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, the basic idea is here: [Demonstration: Day and Night World Clock](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DayAndNightWorldClock/)

Now, to use the images, create an alpha channel using the computed the day-night curve--called "terminator" curve (rasterize it in grayscale), and compose two images using **`ImageCompose`** with the generated alpha channels (**`SetAlphaChannel`** to the second image).

Try the following code:

```
a = Image[ConstantArray[{255, 0, 0}, {200, 300}]];
b = Image[ConstantArray[{0, 255, 0}, {200, 300}]];

(* This is just a made-up mask. Don't mind the Plot[] part *)
mask = Rasterize[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}, PlotRangePadding->0,
    Filling->-1, FillingStyle->Black, Frame->False, 
    Axes->False, ImageSize->{300, 200}, AspectRatio->2/3],
  "Image", ColorSpace->"GrayScale"];

ImageCompose[a, SetAlphaChannel[b, mask]]
```

You should get an image with green and red mixed as below. Now you can replace `a` and `b` with your day and night textures.

> [image: mask]

I have to tell you that although the code there computes pretty close approximation of the actual terminator curve, it is not exact. To compute it accurately (or based on actual data), see: [NOAA: Day Night Terminator](http://sos.noaa.gov/Datasets/dataset.php?id=110)

The following code and output is for the actual images (again the mask is fake):

```
day = ImageResize[day, {2048, 1024}]; (* Match the dimensions *)

mask = Rasterize[
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
    Filling -> -1, FillingStyle -> Black, Frame -> False, 
    Axes -> False, ImageSize -> {2048, 1024}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1024/2048], "Image", ColorSpace -> "GrayScale"];

ImageCompose[night, SetAlphaChannel[day, mask]]
```

> [image: output]

Comment: welcome to the time killer ;-)

Comment: @ruebenko: you are scaring me :)

Comment: It is very easy to lose days here answering questions, editing text, cavorting with the others in the chat room, etc. But, welcome to the club.

Comment: Great many thanks for the editing, which adds a composition example I was actually getting nowhere with on my own :)

Answer (score 8):

Since version 10.0, the functions `DayHemisphere[]`, `NightHemisphere[]`, and `DayNightTerminator[]` are now built-in, and can be used with `GeoGraphics[]`. These three can either take a specified date, and will otherwise default to `Now`. One can now do things like this:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[GrayLevel[0, 2/3]], NightHemisphere[]}, 
            GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["Satellite"], GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular",
            GeoRange -> "World"]
```

[image: day-night map]

which can then be used as a suitable `Texture[]` if wanted.

Comment: I'm slightly disappointed that this has more votes than my previous answer. :P

Answer (score 6):

As Sjoerd shows, `AstronomicalData[]` can be used to determine the altitude of the sun. However, if you do not need too much accuracy, such as in this application, you can use a low-accuracy method for computing the altitude. Most of the formulae I will be using are from (of course) [Jean Meeus's *Astronomical Algorithms*](http://www.willbell.com/math/mc1.HTM).

Some auxiliary routines will be needed. First, one for computing the Julian Day number:

```
Options[jd] = {"Calendar" -> "Gregorian"};

jd[{yr_Integer, mo_Integer, da_?NumericQ, rest___}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{y = yr, m = mo, h}, If[m < 3, y--; m += 12];
         h = Switch[OptionValue["Calendar"],
                    "Gregorian", (Quotient[#, 4] - # + 2) &[Quotient[y, 100]],
                    "Julian", 0,
                    _, Return[$Failed]];
         Floor[365.25 y] + Floor[30.6001 (m + 1)] + da +
         FromDMS[PadRight[{rest}, 3]]/24 + 1720994.5 + h]

jd[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := jd[DateList[], opts]
```

Here's a method for computing the Greenwich Mean Sidereal Time:

```
GMST[{yr_Integer, mo_Integer, da_?NumericQ, rest___}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    Mod[6.697374558 + 0.06570982441908 (jd[{yr, mo, da}, opts] - 2.451545*^6) +
    1.00273790935 FromDMS[PadRight[{rest}, 3]] + 0.000026 ((jd[{yr, mo, da, rest}, opts] -
    2.451545*^6)/36525)^2, 24]

GMST[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := GMST[DateList[], opts]
```

Finally, here's the low-accuracy method for computing the solar altitude:

```
solarAltitude[date_List, {ϕ_, λ_}] := 
 Module[{t, ℳ☉, ℯ, s, ℰ, v, Ω, ℒ0, Λ, ε, α, δ, ℋ},

  t = (jd[date] - 2451545)/36525;

  (* ℳ☉ - mean solar anomaly *)
  ℳ☉ = Mod[(1.28710479305*^6 + t (1.295965810481*^8 + t (-0.5532 + t (1.36*^-4 -
            1.149*^-5 t))))/3600, 360] °;

  (* ℯ - eccentricity of Earth's orbit *)
  ℯ = 0.0167086342 + t (-0.004203654 + t (-0.00126734 +
      t (1.444*^-4 + t (-2.*^-6 + 3.*^-5 t))));

  (* ℰ - eccentric anomaly; approximate solution of Kepler's equation *)
  s = Sin[ℳ☉]; ℰ = ℳ☉ + ℯ s/(s - Sin[ℳ☉ + ℯ] + 1);

  (* v - true anomaly *)
  v = 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[(1 + ℯ)/(1 - ℯ)] Tan[ℰ/2]]/°;

  (* ℒ0 - geometric mean longitude *)
  ℒ0 = (280.46645 + t (36000.76983 + 3.032*^-4 t));

  (* Ω - Meeus's correction for apparent angles *)
  Ω = (125.04 - 1934.136 t) °;

  (* Λ - solar longitude, plus correction for apparent position *)
  Λ = Mod[v + ℒ0 - ℳ☉/°, 360] ° - (0.00569 + 0.00478 Sin[Ω]) °;

  (* ε - mean obliquity of the ecliptic, plus correction for apparent position *)
  ε = (84381.406 + t (-46.836769 + t (-1.831*^-4 + t (0.0020034 +
      t (-5.76*^-7 - 4.34*^-8 t))))) °/3600 + 0.00256 Cos[Ω] °;

  (* α - right ascension, δ - declination *)
  {α, δ} = {ArcTan[Cos[Λ], Sin[Λ] Cos[ε]]/(15 °), ArcSin[Sin[ε] Sin[Λ]]};

  (* ℋ - hour angle *)
  ℋ = 15 ° Mod[FromDMS[GMST[date]] + λ/15 - α, 24];

  ArcSin[Sin[δ] Sin[ϕ °] + Cos[δ] Cos[ϕ °] Cos[ℋ]]/°]
```

A few nice maps:

```
earthDay = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLrc8.jpg"];
earthNight = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCJik.jpg"];
```

Finally, the routine for making a day/night map:

```
Options[DayAndNightMap] = {Sphere -> False, TimeZone :> $TimeZone};

DayAndNightMap[date_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   Module[{h = OptionValue[TimeZone], terminator, dayAndNight},
          terminator = Binarize[
          RegionPlot[Positive[solarAltitude[DatePlus[date, {-h, "Hour"}], {ϕ, λ}]],
                     {λ, -180, 180}, {ϕ, -90, 90}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
                     BoundaryStyle -> None, Frame -> False, ImagePadding -> None, 
                     ImageSize -> {2048, 1024}, PlotPoints -> 45, 
                     PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotStyle -> Black]];

          dayAndNight = RemoveAlphaChannel[ImageCompose[earthDay,
                        SetAlphaChannel[earthNight, terminator]]];

          If[TrueQ[OptionValue[Sphere]],
             ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[λ] Sin[ϕ], Sin[λ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[ϕ]},
                              {λ, -π, π}, {ϕ, 0, π}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False,
                              Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 55,
                              PlotStyle -> Texture[dayAndNight], RotationAction -> "Clip",
                              TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, 1 - #5} &)],
             dayAndNight]]

DayAndNightMap[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := DayAndNightMap[DateList[], opts]
```

I guess an example is in order at this point:

```
DayAndNightMap[{2013, 5, 21, 15, 30, 0}, TimeZone -> 0]
```

[image: a day-and-night map]

For the kids who prefer actual globes:

```
DayAndNightMap[{2013, 5, 21, 15, 30, 0}, Sphere -> True, TimeZone -> 0]
```

[image: a half-lit globe]

Comment: Too bad this doesn't work in v7.  Of course if it did I'd feel obliged to bounty it.  It looks great!  I'll break my usual rule of not voting for answers I cannot test and I'll consider the images proof of function. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, which function(s) aren't in version 7?

Comment: There's no `Texture` so the centerpiece is out.  There is also no `SetAlphaChannel` thought it could be improvised, but please don't go to the effort to do so.

Comment: Ah, I keep forgetting `Texture[]` is new in 8... yes, it would be a bit more complicated to do in version seven.