# Anyone recognize this heatmap?

Tags: visualization

Anyone know the origins of the attached heatmap/daylight overlay? I see it on the Mathematica homepage all the time and I even saw it once on [Wolfram|Alpha launch video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LXhFvdhZMg). I know there are ways to generate both heatmaps and daylight overlays, but does Mathematica have built in functionality that does something like this?

[image: Heatmap]

Yes, I realize this might be an odd question, but it's been bugging me for a while...

Comment: Not exactly built-in, but somebody did ask a question on [generating the day/night terminator in *Mathematica*](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3326) a while back...

Comment: Next time, please ask such casual questions in the [_Mathematica_ chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica) :)

Answer (score 11):

There is much more to this image than meets the eye. To get the complexity and scope of this project (much beyond heat-maps), watch free video [**Development: Enterprise-Class Web Applications**](http://www.wolfram.com/training/videos/DEV013/) about this particular project and [**download presentation slides notebook**](http://www.wolfram.com/training/videos/downloads/DEV013.zip). Below are a few screenshots from the presentation showing some cool parts of the same dashboard that you probably have not seen before yet. Also, for just day-night app take a look at this Demonstration: [**Day and Night World Clock**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DayAndNightWorldClock/) by [Yu-Sung Chang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/820) - the same person who gives the presentation.

[image]

[image]