# How can I put an image on a surface

Tags: plotting, image

I want to paste an image on the surface of a 3D plot. For example consider this image [image]which I want to paste on the surface of this sphere

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, Mesh -> 1]
```

What will be the best way to do that?

### EDIT and Clarification

My main objective is not to make a globe but to find a general way to use any arbitrary image on a surface. I choose the map and sphere just as an example (a popular one). `Texture` is a good option, but I find some difficulty to use it with `ContourPlot3D` or `Plot3D`. To make my point clear, I would request to show me an example with this image [image] and the following surface,

```
Plot3D[Abs[x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/how-to-make-a-3d-globe/3660#3660) should probably do it.

Comment: Look up `Texture` in Mathematica's document center. There are several examples that do precisely this.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3632/57

Comment: Come on, just do *exactly the same thing*: `Plot3D[Abs[x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Texture[Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/XVgk0.jpg"]], Lighting -> "Neutral"]`

Answer (score 9):

This question is *very* similar to [How to make a 3D globe](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/).  There is some difference, as that question dealt with building a globe from scratch, whereas this question has a predefined image.  There is a little difference in that you'll need to manually trim the boundary of your image.  Here's how did it:

```
pic = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JpK4.jpg"];
{width, height} = ImageDimensions[pic];
w = 40; h = 45;
pic = ImageTake[pic, {h, height - h}, {w, width - w}];
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]} ,
  {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100,
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, 1 - #5} &), Boxed -> False,
  PlotStyle -> Texture[Show[pic, ImageSize -> 1000]],
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, RotationAction -> "Clip",
  ViewPoint -> {-2.026774, 2.07922, 1.73753418},
  ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: @smtg using Mark McClure's answer to fulfill your requirements in the Edit/Clarification: `Plot3D[Abs[x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, 1 - #2} &), PlotStyle -> Texture[Show[pic, ImageSize -> 1000]], Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> False]`  The only difference is in the `TextureCoordinateFunction`.

Answer (score 8):

You could use *ContourPlot3D*, but I'd use *SphericalPlot3D* instead. That's because you're plotting a spere anyways and SphericalPlot3D seems to be the better functionality on that matter.

I leave the rest of the options such as in your example for ContourPlot3D.

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
    MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> True, 
    TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, 1 - #4} &), 
    PlotStyle -> 
        Directive[Texture[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JpK4.jpg"]], 
        Specularity[White, 50]], Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

Personally I'd remove any mesh, axis and boxes, but this is just a matter of taste.

[image]