# Plotting the Equation of Time: SiderealTime and SunPosition

Tags: astronomy

> The equation of time describes the discrepancy between two kinds of solar time. The word equation is used in the medieval sense of reconcile a difference. The two times that differ are the apparent solar time, which directly tracks the motion of the sun, and mean solar time, which tracks a theoretical "mean" sun with noons 24 hours apart.

(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time))

In the *Mathematica* documentation for [`SiderealTime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SiderealTime.html), there is an "application" sample to "plot the equation of time by finding the difference between the Sun's right ascension at noon and the sidereal time at noon":

```
sunpos = SunPosition[GeoPosition[{0, 0}], 
   DateRange[DateObject[{2014, 1, 1, 12, 0}, TimeZone -> 0], 
    DateObject[{2014, 12, 31, 12, 0}, TimeZone -> 0], 10], 
   CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"];

stime = SiderealTime[GeoPosition[{0, 0}], 
   DateRange[DateObject[{2014, 1, 1, 12, 0}, TimeZone -> 0], 
    DateObject[{2014, 12, 31, 12, 0}, TimeZone -> 0], 10]];

equationoftime = 
  TimeSeriesThread[With[{diff = First[#][[1]] - Last[#]},
     UnitConvert[
      Mod[diff, Quantity[24, "HoursOfRightAscension"], 
       Quantity[-12, "HoursOfRightAscension"]], 
      "MinutesOfRightAscension"]] &, {sunpos, stime}];

DateListPlot[equationoftime, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, the "amplitude" of the plot is different from the "amplitude" of the plot on Wikipedia. On may sources, graphical or tabular, the first maximum is less than $15^m$ and the last minimum is deeper than $-15^m$.

So, my questions (if someone knows):

1. What is the reason for these differences
2. What effects are taken into account by these astronomical functions? (nutation?) For example does `SiderealTime` return the LAST or the mean ST?
3. What are the bibliographic sources and the formula used by these astronomical functions?

Comment: If you can get hold of a copy of Meeus, you could try implementing his formulae for comparison. (I'm still sad about losing my copy.)

Comment: @J.M. [This one](http://www.amazon.com/Astronomical-Algorithms-Jean-Meeus/dp/0943396611)?

Comment: Yes, that. $\phantom{}$

Comment: @J.M. - Brilliant book. Three copies on shelf here, replaced with new as copies became beat up from use. That's [my animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time#Graphical_representation) on the Wikipedia page, built *long* ago when teaching my then very young daughter Mathematica (and the building of a sundial at the same time). Memories...

Comment: @ciao, nice! Do you still have the code for it lying around somewhere?

Comment: @J.M. - Yes, I never delete old code - worst case gets archived to my robotic archive library. But it's on a machine at a home I'm seldom at and have not set up for remote access. Happy to send it when I'm there next, but could be some time...

Comment: @ciao, OK, just ping me when you can.

Answer (score 3):

I dug up my old (version 8) routine for the equation of time, for comparison's sake. The formulae involved are, as always, from [Jean Meeus's *Astronomical Algorithms*](http://www.willbell.com/math/mc1.HTM).

```
(* Julian day number *)
Options[jd] = {"Calendar" -> "Gregorian"};

jd[{yr_Integer, mo_Integer, da_?NumericQ, rest___}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{y = yr, m = mo, h}, If[m < 3, y--; m += 12];
         h = Switch[OptionValue["Calendar"],
                    "Gregorian", (Quotient[#, 4] - # + 2) &[Quotient[y, 100]],
                    "Julian", 0,
                    _, Return[$Failed]];
         Floor[365.25 y] + Floor[30.6001 (m + 1)] + da +
         FromDMS[PadRight[{rest}, 3]]/24 + 1720994.5 + h]

jd[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := jd[DateList[], opts]

equationOfTime[date_List] := 
 Module[{t = (jd[date] - 2451545)/36525, ε, ℒ0, ℯ, ℳ☉, y},

        (* ε - mean obliquity of the ecliptic *)
        ε = (84381.406 + t (-46.836769 + t (-1.831*^-4 + t (0.0020034 + t (-5.76*^-7 -
             4.34*^-8 t))))) °/3600;

        (* ℒ0 - geometric mean longitude *)
        ℒ0 = Mod[(280.4664567 + t (36000.76982779 + t (3.032028*^-2 + t (1/49931 -
                 t (t/1.53*^4 + t/2*^6))))), 360] °;

        (* ℯ - eccentricity of Earth's orbit *)
        ℯ = 0.0167086342 + t (-0.004203654 + t (-0.00126734 + t (1.444*^-4 +
            t (-2.*^-6 + 3.*^-5 t))));

        (* ℳ☉ - mean solar anomaly *)
        ℳ☉ = Mod[(1.28710479305*^6 + t (1.295965810481*^8 + t (-0.5532 + t (1.36*^-4 -
                  1.149*^-5 t))))/3600, 360] °;

        y = Tan[ε/2]^2;
        4 (-y Sin[2 ℒ0] + 2 ℯ Sin[ℳ☉] - 4 ℯ y Sin[ℳ☉] Cos[2 ℒ0] +
           y^2 Sin[4 ℒ0]/2 + 5 ℯ^2/4 Sin[2 ℳ☉])/°]
```

(N.B. Altho `JulianDate[]` is now built-in, for some reason it was unable to reproduce the test dates from Meeus, so I fell back to my old `jd[]` routine, as previously seen [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11237) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25681).)

Compare:

```
dr = DateRange[DateObject[{2014, 1, 1, 12, 0}, TimeZone -> 0],
               DateObject[{2014, 12, 31, 12, 0}, TimeZone -> 0], 10];
sunpos = SunPosition[GeoPosition[{0, 0}], dr, CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"];
stime = SiderealTime[GeoPosition[{0, 0}], dr];
eotDocs = TimeSeriesThread[With[{diff = First[#][[1]] - Last[#]}, 
          UnitConvert[Mod[diff, Quantity[24, "HoursOfRightAscension"], 
                          Quantity[-12, "HoursOfRightAscension"]], 
                      "MinutesOfRightAscension"]] &, {sunpos, stime}];
eotMeeus = TimeSeries[Transpose[{dr, Composition[equationOfTime, DateList] /@ dr}]];
DateListPlot[{eotDocs, eotMeeus},
             FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> {"Docs", "Meeus"}]
```

[image: equation of time from different methods]

where it can be seen that Meeus's method hews more closely to the figures featured at Wikipedia. (At this juncture, I should note that the equation of time exhibits an ambiguity in sign, so if you are comparing this with other sources, it may well be that `equationOfTime[]` returns the negative of the convention of your reference.)

As to why there is a difference, without seeing how `SunPosition[]` and `SiderealTime[]` were implemented, there is not much to say.